# Linq-to-Sql LoadWith returns null

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

In my code I have this:

```
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Place>(p => p.Address);
context.LoadOptions = dlo;

var places = context.Places.Where(p => p.ID >= 100 && p.ID <= 200);
```

The problem is the Address returned is null and I don't know why.

Comment: Is `p.Address` a valid navigation property? Does it work when you use it in other queries?

Comment: Address is an association in Place table to Address table

Comment: I excuted command in sql server and it returns the wanted result but when I come to use the Address it appears as null

Comment: Your question says the adress (single) is null; but there are multiple places possible in this result set, some might have an address others not; are you sure you are checking the right place. What happen when you change the query to one single id of a place that has address for sure |  e.g. p.ID == 121

Comment: thank you dear for your replay, I tried this but unfortunately it didn't work
I think it is something related to table association in dbml, can be ?
my project is asp.net

Answer (score 0):

The probelm was child property in the association it was set true when I changed it to false it works fine.
thank you all for help